# How do you use memcached (not memcache) with PHP (part 3)

Tags: php, caching

On the first page, I have this

```
// start memcached
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
$key = 'test_1';
$test_data = array(....);
$m->set($key, $test_data);
// end memcached
```

OK, so far. On the next page,

```
// start memcached
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
var_dump($m->get('test_1'));
// end memcached
```

The following error occured:

```
bool(false)
```

The bool(false) error occurs even after the codes are placed on the same script.

Comment: Both `$m->addServer()` and `$m->set()` return boolean values. Check them to be sure they are true.  Check the output [from `$m->getResultMessage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.getresultmessage.php) if they fail.

Comment: Both $m->addServer() and $m->set() return true.

The following error occured:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Comment: Hmm that doesn't quite make sense, because you should have also had the same error when calling `$m->addServer()` if `$m` was not an object.  Check `var_dump($m);` after instantiating and after `addServer()`

Comment: I ran thu the scripts again, but this time there was no errors. The error only happens after I added code to check $m for true/false..........var_dump($m->get('test_1')) still returns bool(false);